# Prove that $\sum_{k=m}^n x_k>1-\dfrac{a_m}{a_n}\forall n\geq m $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ {a_k}$ be an unbounded,strictly increasing  sequence of  positive real numbers and $x_k=\dfrac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_{k+1}}$. Prove that $\sum_{k=m}^n x_k>1-\dfrac{a_m}{a_n}\forall n\geq m $ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ diverges to $+\infty.$

What I thought: $\sum_{k=m}^n x_k=\sum_{k=m}^n(1-\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}})$

As $0<\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}<1$,taking $\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}=1-\dfrac{1}{k}$ for each $m\leq k \leq n$.

But i cant carry it more .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=m}^n x_k=\sum_{k=m}^n {a_{k+1}-a_k \over a_{k+1}}>\sum_{k=m}^n {a_{k+1}-a_k \over a_{n+1}}={a_{n+1}-a_m\over a_{n+1}}=1-{a_m \over a_{n+1}}>1-{a_m \over a_{n}}$$

Comment: It does not make a great difference, but the definition of $x_k$ has $a_{k+1}$ in the denominator, not $a_k$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll fix that.

Comment: Note that the question has actually been answered before (and the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1544037/42969 to the "duplicate" seems to have the same minor error).

Comment: Yeah I also saw the comment after I answered and could see somebody had answered it. It was  a mere coincidence that I made a similar mistake though..